# nagios Error: Could not read object configuration data

Tags: error-logging, nagios

I have a brand new install of nagios3 on ubuntu 12.04. After I log in to the web interface and click any link I get the error:

```
Error: Could not read object configuration data!

Here are some things you should check in order to resolve this error:
Verify configuration options using the -v command-line option to check for errors.
Check the Nagios log file for messages relating to startup or status data errors.
```

I ran it with the -v option and it reported no errors:

```
Total Warnings: 0
Total Errors:   0

Things look okay - No serious problems were detected during the pre-flight check
```

The nagios log and apache error log and debug log all have nothing regarding this. Does anyone know how to turn on logging that will give me some kind of useful error? Or if anyone knows how to fix this specific problem without additional logging, I guess that's okay too.

Thanks!

Comment: What user account did you use?  Did you config your cgi.cfg file?  Does the user your httpd server is running as, have access to your nagios.cfg file??

Answer (score 0):

Possibly an issue with permissions. 
/var/cache/nagios3 probably has wrong user/group or permissions set.